# I want to take a variable from one form and give it to a label in another how do I do this

Tags: c#

Ok so I have six variables in one form that all change when various methods are invoked via buttons.

In another form I have six corresponding labels. I want to take the variables from the first form and set the `SomeLabel.text` in the second form when the button on the first form is pressed.

I've been trying to do this in this fashion `Name=Mainform.InitializeComponent.SomeLabel.Text;` but that doesn't work. I know the `InitializeComponent` method is private. I've tried changing it to public but that didn't prove fruitful either(also not good coding).  So I came here to ask how I would do this. I was thinking about using a get and set setup but I'm still unable to access the label from the first form. I didn't include my code because nothing is broken in it and all the pieces that are needed are in the post.

Comment: can you show the code where you open second form? is it from first form?

Comment: I was just planning to initialize it the same way the first form does by using `SecondForm.InitializeComponent();`I guess that probably won't work either since it's private.

Answer (score 1):

You can either share a variable using `public/internal Method` or using `public / internal properties'

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm.SetTextLabel1("Hello world");
            //or
            frm.Label1Text = "HEllo world again";
        }
    }
}


using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //using method to set the value of label
        public void SetTextLabel1(string value)
        {

            label1.Text = value;
        }

        //using property to set the value of label
        public string Label1Text
        {
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's mostly going well integrating it into my forms. The only thing thats holding me up now is that I keep getting this error `Cannot assign to 'SetInfo' because it is a 'method group'` around this 
`public void StatTransfer()
  {
   mForm.SetInfo = Name;
  }`

function and this is the `public void SetInfo(string value)
  {
   pcNameLabel.Text = value; 
  }`

is the base setinfo method.

Comment: you are trying to create SetInfo method, it should have been a property, and above all u dont need both, either of them will get the job done !

Answer (score 0):

Set **Modifier** property of label to **Public**. So you can access to label from Form object.

Comment: setting modifier of label to public is a bad coding practice!

Comment: @AppDeveloper, I answer to "I'm still unable to access the label from the first form"

Comment: yah right, but still sticking to code standing is a better way to learn coding!

Comment: @RezaArab, it's an answer yes. And yes we've all done it on occasion, but it's a last resort not a first one.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's the quick and dirty way which you've already been provided. Or there's write a class to hold this common data ,add a method to call from form1's button that fires an event, that form2 subscribes to, reads the data and updates it's labels. They both know about the intermediate class but neither needs to know anything about the other.

Comment: I'll probably do it by using a common data class as you suggest since the quick and dirty way doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: That suggests your design is too clean for it to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take those six variables as Public static in form2.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.VariableLable1 = "a";
        Form2.VariableLable2 = "b";
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{  
    public static string VariableLable1,VariableLable2;
    private void form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lable1.Text = VariableLable1;
        Lable1.Text = VariableLable2;
    }
}
```